# Is there a way to configure Visual Studio 2022 to auto insert parentheses when method selected from suggestion list?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

I want Visual Studio 2022 to put parenthesis when I insert a method from the suggestion list and move the cursor between the parenthesis. Is there any free extension that does this? Is it natively supported?

Current behaviour when inserted a method from list:
`Console.WriteLine$cursor$`
Expected behaviour when inserted a method from list:
`Console.WriteLine($cursor$)`

It would be helpfull if you point the direction of how to create such an extension that does what I described. I would consider to create an extension if there is no such a solution.

Currently I'm using CodeRush and Auto Surrond extensions which I couldn't find such an option in the settings of these extensions. Also found this [issue in github](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/12363) I think there has been a long discussion for such an easy feature.

Comment: Works for me. When I hit "Enter" or "Tab" after selecting an item in the list, the parenthesis are inserted automatically and the cursor is between them.

Comment: @PMF Did you change any setting? When I hit "Enter" after selecting an item behaviour is as I described before. If I hit semicolon it puts parenthesis and moves the cursor to the end of the line. It doesn't matter if method needs a parameter or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone in reddit helped me to find a solution.

### Solution

Go to

> Tool > Options > Text Editor > C# > IntelliSense

and enable **Tab twice to insert arguments (experimental)**

Pressing the Tab key twice after selecting a method from suggestions will now insert the parenthesis and place to cursor between them.

Comment: Your answer is helpful, you can make it mark so that it can help more people

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).